# Cant change database field varchar length (error 500)

Tags: database, phpmyadmin, varchar

I'm in my phpmyadmin and I'm trying to increase a column in a table that is currently **varchar(7)** to **varchar(10)**. 
:
I select the column to change it and then enter 10 in the length/values field and click save.

Every time I attempt this I get: Error Code 500 - 'Internal Server Error' (see attached image)

[image: error code 500 when changing varchar length]

Comment: This table does have 84400+ entries in it and is being used by several users most of the time. I considered that this may be not helping matters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind! I cut off all the users for a short period and managed to increase the varchars length.